# google visualization "p Property" supported attributes

Tags: google-visualization

I want to make the value ("v") appear on rollover using the standard HTML title attribute (among placing other attributes for other purposes).

The visualization docs say this can be done via the "p Property". However, from my code below ONLY className get rendered as an attribute in the td tags.

Given the "style" attribute is an example directly copied from the documentation - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#cell_object, I assume i'm doing something wrong. Can you see what it might be?

**Cell Object:**

```
{
      "v": "\/?s=mi+shampoo+adecuado?&submit=Buscar",
      "f": "\/?s=m...uscar",
      "p": {
        "title": "\/?s=mi+shampoo+adecuado?&submit=Buscar",
        "style": "border: 1px solid green;",
        "className": "randomCls",
        "data-title": "\/?s=mi+shampoo+adecuado?&submit=Buscar"
      }
    },
```

**visualization code**

```
var table = new google.visualization.DataTable();
for(var j=0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
    table.addColumn(typeof data[1][j].v,data[0][j]);
}
data.shift();
table.addRows(data);
var ac = new google.visualization.Table(graph.get(0)); // AreaChart

ac.draw(table, {
    backgroundColor: {fill:'#d4d4d4'},
    colors : ["#999999",'#004087']
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Table visualization only supports ["className" and "style" properties](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#customproperties) for cells.  If you need to apply additional HTML properties to cells, you will have to write custom code to parse the `<table>` element created by the visualization and add the properties to `<td>` elements manually.  If you can put the properties on the cell contents instead of the `<td>` elements, you can set the formatted values of the cells to contain whatever HTML you need.

Comment: thank you, i was trying to avoid the extra step, but went ahead and did that anyway using ChartWrapper in my answer below.

Regarding "you can put the properties on the cell contents instead of the <td> elements", are you suggesting i just set the <td> to something like `<td><span title="full value">formatted value</span></td>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @asgallant for clarification on the supported attributes. So, here's the code accordingly:

```
var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'Table',
            dataTable: table,
            options: {backgroundColor: {fill:'#d4d4d4'}, colors : ["#999999",'#004087'], allowHtml:true},
            containerId: 'widget'+wid
});

google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper, 'ready', function() {
    graph.find(".tipFlag").each(function(){
         var v = $(this).attr("class").substring("tipFlag ".length);
         $(this).attr("title", v);
    });
});

wrapper.draw();
```

where the new cell objects look like:

```
{
  "v": "\/?s=mi+shampoo+adecuado?&submit=Buscar",
  "f": "\/?s=m...uscar",
  "p": {
    "className": "tipFlag \/?s=mi+shampoo+adecuado?&submit=Buscar",
  }
},
```